# OBIEE 12c : Facing issue in getting the components started(Could not load CSF library)

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-bi

I am  facing few challenges when performing a fresh installation of **obiee12c(12.2.1.3)** in our test environment(**RHEL6**).

As soon as i installed and ran the configuration utility for obiee, we see the **following components has not been started** after the executing the configuration script (installation of weblogic and obiee are successful)

```
OBIPS
OBISCH
OBIS

[CONFIG] [BI Startup] [Start all Servers]:2018-02-12T04:22:06.912-0500 Name Type Machine Status

[CONFIG] [BI Startup] [Start all Servers]:2018-02-12T04:22:06.913-0500 obips1 OBIPS ----------------- SHUTDOWN

[CONFIG] [BI Startup] [Start all Servers]:2018-02-12T04:22:06.913-0500 obisch1 OBISCH ----------------- SHUTDOWN

[CONFIG] [BI Startup] [Start all Servers]:2018-02-12T04:22:06.913-0500 obis1 OBIS ----------------- SHUTDOWN
```

Below are the log snippets that we could capture from the respective server logs:

**obis1 logs:**

```
"Oracle BI Server startup failed.[nQSError: 46136] Could not load CSF library libnqcsfwrapper64.so"
```

**obisch/logs :**

```
[2018-02-12T04:18:16.187-05:00] [OBISCH] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: service1] [tid: df52c720] [68008] Scheduler Error: [nQSError: 46136] Could not load CSF library libnqcsfwrapper64.so
```

**obips1 :**

```
<Feb 19, 2018 9:58:13 AM EST> <INFO> <NodeManager ComponentManager> <ORACLE_OBICCS_HOSTS=---------------------:9508>

/tech/obiee/Oracle/products/Oracle_Home/bi/bifoundation/web/bin/sawserver: error while loading shared libraries: libclntshcore.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**OS level details:**

```
uname -a : Linux ------------------------------------- 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 13 00:51:26 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**database version :** 12.1.0.2

Any help on this would be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your obiee12c installation may connect to a database requiring network encryption.

Try to disable it on the database side with adding this line to database instance sqlnet.ora :

```
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = rejected
```

Source : https://debaatobiee.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/obiee-12c-csf-error-or-ofm-security-error-or/